# Use $E[(X\leq Y)^2]$ to obtain lower and upper bounds of $E[XY]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are not statistically independent.

Tags: probability, expectation

> Use $E[(X\leq Y)^2]$ to obtain lower and upper bounds of $E[XY]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are not statistically independent.

I don't understand what $(X\leq Y)^2$ supposed to mean. Is it a typo error?

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to write $E[(X\leq Y)^2]$. I guess there is typo, it should be $E[(X-Y)^2]$

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the expectation of the random variable taking value $1$ if $X\leq Y$ and $0$ otherwise. But then there would be no reason to take the square (which equals it). Typo I think.